# How to solve the problem of (node:5124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error:

Tags: sql, node.js, client-server, connection-pooling

I am writing a module for the client to request data from the server.
The front-end request code is as follows:

```
let batch = 2048;
            let start = i * batch - 1;
            let end = (i + 1) * batch;
            let lastMaxIndex = 2 ** (i + 9) - 1;
            const updateUrl =  `/line_chart/update?start=${start}&end=${end}&lastMaxIndex=${lastMaxIndex}&width=${2 ** (Math.ceil(Math.log2(payload.width)))}`;
            const data = get(context.state, updateUrl);
            console.log(data);
            const res = await data;
```

and the server-side code is as follows:

```
async function updatee(req,res){
    const query = req.query;
    let lastMaxIndex = query.lastMaxIndex;
    // const preDeleteSql = `delete t,v from "public"."test" where t = lastMaxIndex`
    // pool.query(preDeleteSql)
    const querySQL = `SELECT t,v FROM "raw_data"."test" where t>$1 and t<$2 ORDER by t ASC`
    const params = [];
    // console.log(query.width)
    params.push(query.start);
    params.push(query.end);
    const sqlQuery = {
        text: querySQL,
        values: params
    }
    const queryData = await pool.query(sqlQuery);
    // computeTableFlag(queryData);
   // return
    let data = queryData.rows;

    
    let queryTemp = `SELECT i,minvd,maxvd FROM "om3"."encode_test" where i=$1`
    const params1 = [];
    params1.push(-1);
    const queryTempSql = {
        text:  queryTemp,
        values: params1
    }
    let TempData = await pool.query(queryTempSql);
    min = Math.min(minV[0],TempData.rows[0]['minvd']);
    max = Math.max(maxV[0],TempData.rows[0]['maxvd']);
   
    // const queryTemp1 = `INSERT INTO om3.encode_test(i,minvd,maxvd) values(2*${lastMaxIndex}+1,${TempData.rows[0]['minvd']}-${minV[0]},${TempData.rows[0]['maxvd']}-${maxV[0]})`
    // await pool.query(queryTemp1);
    

    const queryTemp1 = `INSERT INTO om3.encode_test(i,minvd,maxvd) values(2*${lastMaxIndex}+1,${TempData.rows[0]['minvd']}-${minV[0]},${TempData.rows[0]['maxvd']}-${maxV[0]})`

    try {
        await pool.query(queryTemp1);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error executing query:', err);
      }

    const preDeleteSql = `delete from "om3"."encode_test" where i = ${-1}`
    await pool.query(preDeleteSql);
```

But when I run to

```
 const queryTemp1 = `INSERT INTO om3.encode_test(i,minvd,maxvd) values(2*${lastMaxIndex}+1,${TempData.rows[0]['minvd']}-${minV[0]},${TempData.rows[0]['maxvd']}-${maxV[0]})`
  try {
        await pool.query(queryTemp1);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error executing query:', err);
      }
```

it will return me an error:

```
(node:5124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: 
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\A\Desktop\OM_3_code\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\A\Desktop\OM_3_code\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\A\Desktop\OM_3_code\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\A\Desktop\OM_3_code\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:5124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). 
(rejection id: 7)
```

I have tried the `try...catch` after searching the Internet. But it didn't work. I'm sure it's not the problem of SQL, because even if I run the following SQL before that SQL, it will return the same error.

```
const preDeleteSql = `delete from "om3"."encode_test" where i = ${-1}`
await pool.query(preDeleteSql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be useful that there is an event `unhandledRejection` on `process` in which you can listen for any promise rejection.

```js
function rejectedPromise() {
  return Promise.reject("Any reason");
}

rejectedPromise();

process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

And remember, whenever you have to use `unhandledRejection` it's better to restart your process and use it just for the sake of logging and bug finding.